# Код Delphi 2 быстрее чем Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi

Решил перенести на платформу XE8 программу, созданную на Delphi 2 в 2000г. и полученную по наследству. После переноса все работает, но в результате сильно вырос ехе-шник (с 4МБ до 9МБ, это понятно), но волнует другое. Сильно увеличилось время загрузки (выгрузки) файла данных (обычный текстовый файл). По алгоритму программа из текстового файла создает множество объектов (компонентов схемы) с которыми работает пользователь, а результат снова возвращается в текстовый файл. Так вот загрузка (выгрузка) этого файла занимает значительно большее время по сравнению с прародительницей (Delphi 2). Т.к. исходный текст практически не менялся, возникает вопрос:

При прослеживании обработки одного объекта с помощью профилировщика, кажется нашел узкое место, где имеет место максимальная задержка, это код вида

```
parent := pFrm^;
```

где `parent` свойство создаваемого компонента на основе данных из текстового файла, а `pFrm` указатель на основною форму. Т.к. объектов – компонентов несколько сотен а то и тысяч набегает приличное время. Удивляет что на обработку того же кода  Delphi 2 затрачивает времени в несколько раз меньше.

Возможно кто-либо уже сталкивался с подобными вопросами и знает решение. Либо смириться, что код Delphi 2 быстрее чем у XE8.....
**продолжение после чтения ответов**
На ХЕ8 я делал ехе-ник и х32 и х64 и особой разницы в скорости не заметил т.к. ехе-ник созданный Delphi-2 в разы превосходит ехе-ник созданный на ХЕ8 ( Допустим один и тот же файл *.txt, ХЕ8 обрабатывает (грузит) 2мин, а ехе-ник созданный Delphi-2 -40сек). Естественно я пробовал пуски вне среды разработки ХЕ8.   Профилир-м я разбивал весь код создания 1-го объекта на куски и таким способом вышел на  строку tmах  (parent := pFrm^;). Это время   в среднем (зависит от типа объекта) составляет 120мсек (0,12сек). Если 1000*0,12=120сек, что тоже где-то подтверждает. Да, я тоже думал про UNICODE, но ведь компилятор все воспринимает и не жалуется, да и объекты получаются такие же как и у ехе-ника созданного Delphi-2. Я не считаю себя очень крутым программистом по XE8, возможно необходимо дать к-н дополнительные директивы компилятору или настройку среды? Мне тоже не очень верится, что может быть такая разница в производительности между версиями

Comment: x32 vs x64 не при чём?

Comment: AnsiString vs Unicode String ни при чём?

Comment: ну уж товарищи, не в _несколько раз_ будет отличаться.

Comment: вообще профилировщиком сравнить бы оба варианта. а не искать максимальную задержку в хе8, она может такой же большой быть и во 2м

Comment: Железо и ОС те же самые?

Comment: Естественно комп. один и тот же

Comment: Напишите [минимально-воспроизводимый код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), на котором можно заметить тормоза в XE8 и который будет летать в D2. Тогда можно будет сказать, в чём проблема. А так получается сплошное гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Как поиск решения: возможно тормозит взятие указателя на форму (тогда нужно взять указатель за пределами цикла один раз), возможно тормозит присваивание (так как это свойство компонента). Пробуйте профайлером (или просто замером времени) узнать.

Comment: к сожалению на моих 2-х компах стоит W10 и W8 и Ву

Comment: Тормозит как раз присвоение, с каждым циклом форма набирает кол-во комп-в и раздувается в размере и становится тяжелой для присвоения (это я так подумаю), потому что на первых циклах эта операция занимает до 10мсек (зависит также от рожденного объекта). Вопрос как раз сводится к тому можно ли как то настроить компилятор (среду XE8), что бы ехе-ник по скорости приближался к DELPHI-2 или остается только X64 (надежда)

Comment: А зачем вам "указатель на основную форму", если переменная форма сама по себе - указатель?..

Comment: таким образом я привязываю динамически созданный компонент к главной форме, место где они будут отображаться. Без привязки трудно управлять всем множеством комп-в

Comment: @НиколайСаенко вам про то говорят, зачем в принципе писать `pFrm^`, если `myForm : TForm` и так само по себе является указателем. у вас там указатель на указатель что ли? я этого момента тоже не понял изначально при прочтении вопроса, но спрашивать не стал.

Comment: Вручную напишите свою процедуру измерения, использую gettickcount. В основном тормозит выделение памяти (мог поменяться менеджер) . Также могли типы данных немного поменятся и настройки компилятора (Alignment). Может быть отладачная информация включена? "parent := pFrm^;" - посмотрите в ассемлере этот код, сравните, думаю это должно развеять сомнения, что он не влияет на скорость вообще никак (можно сделать цикл отдельный с этой операцией и вермя засечь)

Comment: "parent := pFrm^;" согласен что причина не здесь, а в другом месте, просто она здесь проявилась. Кажется я ее нашел но пока еще не разобрался до конца да и долго описывать. Когда прояснится постараюсь описать и спросить совета т.к. пока не вижу весь алгоритм до конца, просто программа очень большая и заковыристая.  Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вы не пробовали воспользоваться каким-нибудь другим типом профайлера? Как-то очень неправдоподобно, что узким местом может быть банальное разыменовывание указателя, если только их там не 100 000 000 штук. *Обратите внимание, что сам процесс замера скорости искажает её.* Так что попробуйте составить тестовое приложение в котором вы будете сравнивать конкретные операции вне привязки к другим, в т.ч. замерам скорости профайлером.

Также проверьте, что у вас релизная сборка, включены оптимизации, и отключены всякие дебажные фичи.

Comment: +1 если из среды запускать в дебаге, то скорость падает катастрофически.